# Amplify not working properly with react-router

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, react-router, aws-amplify

Following this [official tutorial from Amazon's 'getting started' section](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/), I managed to get to Module 3 and get authentication to work. However, when trying to make an 'admin' page for my app with react-router, redirecting to the new page just skips the whole authentication form.

Admin.tsx:

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import React from 'react';
import { Menu, Three } from '../components'

import { Global, css } from '@emotion/react';

import styles from '../styles/App.module.css'
import { useAppDispatch } from '../redux/hooks';

function Admin() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Global styles={css`
          body{
            margin: 0;
          }
        `}
      />
      <Menu className={styles.menuContainer}/>
      <Three className={styles.threeContainer}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(Admin);
```

This works when importing the module in my index.tsx file normally.

When I try to do it through react-router, as such:

Router.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';
import Admin from './pages/Admin';

export function Router(){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<App/>}/>
                <Route path='/admin' element={<Admin/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './aws-exports';

import { Router } from './Router';

Amplify.configure(config);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router/>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

..it doesn't show me the authentication form at all, just renders the module normally.

Are these just incompatible, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that rendering `<Admin />` directly in `index.tsx` works as expected, but that when rendering the router and `<Route path='/admin' element={<Admin />} />` the authentication doesn't work and the admin UI is just rendered? Are you sure whatever user you are using isn't/wasn't still authenticated and thus not redirected to log in? If you de-authenticate the user does the routing code then work as expected? I think we need more context. Can you [edit] to clarify what the expected behavior *should* be and what reproduction steps you have to produce the issue?

Comment: @stealing_society I've developed a production app using mostly similar architecture to yours. Why not implement `@aws-amplify/ui-react` module as the tutorial mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

Try checking out the guide on the Amplify UI docs site: [How to create an application with protected routes using the Authenticator component](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/guides/auth-protected#adding-the-router-and-protecting-routes) This goes over wrapping the app in `<Authenticator.Provider>` which allows you to use the useAuthenticator hook within your route components.

Comment: link not working